# Function for extracting the smallest value from data set [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, function

I have already made a function which extracts all temeperatures from a data-set for a certain time for a given month and year.

Which looks like:  `exctractperiod(data, year, month, time)`

This will as previously said extract all temperatures for a particular month at a time say 1400.

I now want to find a minimum temperature for a certain month say january across many years. For example if I look at the month january between the year 1997 and 2006. Now I want the lowest registered temperatue for Janauary between 1997-2006.

My progress so far is the code below:

```
function [algo] = getMiniserieone(data, startYear, endYear, time)

v = zeros(12,2); 

for month = 1:12
  for year  = startYear:1:endYear

     p = extractperiodtwo(data, year, month, time);

     q = min(p);

    v(month,1) = v(month,1) + q;
    v(month,2) = v(month,2) + 1;

    algo = v(12,2);
  end
end 
end
```

I do however get the error message:

```
    Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 
   1-by-1 and the size of the right
    side is 0-by-1.
```

When calling the function in the command window:

`>> getMiniserieone(data, 1996, 2006, 1400)`

---

```
Error in getMiniserieone (line 12)
    v(month,1) = v(month,1) + q;
```

But I have not been able remedy this.

My intention with the program above is to lets say for the years between 1996-2006 for a particular time extract the lowest temperature for all months between January and December. Meaning that between the years 1996-2006 for january for a certain time, say 1300, I want the lowest temperature for that month at that time. Then store it in my vector `v` column 1, column 2 will then denote the month.

My question is how I can fix this, i'm not really sure what the error message means? Does it maybe mean that q is not a single element value?

I hope the information given was ample enough to understand the problem, if not feel free to ask.

---

As requested, the code for `extractPeriod()`

```
function [mdata] = extractperiodtwo(data, year, month, time)

x = year*100 +month;

k = find( floor(TEMPUF(:,1)/100) == x & (data(:,2)==time));

mdata = data(k,3);

end
```

Comment: It is likely your method `extractperiodtwo` returns some unexpected value.  Try printing out p and q, and see if it makes sense.

Comment: You're right. Apparently there was no time: 1400 in the dataset.  But I do not however get an expected answer.  Now when I tried `>> getMiniseriesone(data, 1997,2002,1200)` I get the answer 7. Where I am supposed, or expecting, to get a vector with 2 columns and 12 rows where all the lowest temperatures are on the first column and on the second one there should be the corresponding month.

Comment: Move algo to outside and after the for-loops. Also, algo is getting assigned the position v(12,2)... I think you want `algo = v;` to get all 12 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: @Khlick I see. It helped moving algo outside the loops and setting `algo = v;`. The vector i'm getting now however is very inflated. For example, the first row has the values `-743.90` and `37 `. It's a little funny considering how long I've tried getting this right, but very wrong. It might not be looping as I envisaged.

Comment: Maybe the problem now is in the extractperiod function? Or maybe the data have an unexpected format. Having both the formatting for the data and the  code for the extractperiod function would make it easier to give you the right answer.

Comment: @Khlick I'm fairly new to matlab and programming in general. What do you mean by " formatting for the data", how it looks? Also, would you like for me to include my code for `extractperiod` in the orignal post? I do however know that the function `extractperiod()` works, but it might interact poorly with `getMiniserieone()`.

Comment: No worries. Having the code for `extractperiod` would be helpful to understand how 'getMiniserieone` should interact with it. With regard to the data set, is it a matrix? A struct? A cell array? A Table? Etc.. And how are you accessing specific elements of it? The actual data isn't needed, just information on the formatting / structure.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I understand. Regarding my data set, it is a numerix matrix which consists of over 4*10^5 rows and only 3 columns. 
Each column denotes different information. So for the the `first column `it denotes what year/month/date with the format YYYYMMDD, `second column` denotes the time in terms of 700, 1200 and so on(all times are not defined though) and lastly the `third column` which denotes the temperature. I've already revised my orignal post so it now include the function for `extractperiodtwo()`.

Comment: Sorry, 1 more question and I think I may have a solution. Is `TEMPUF` mean to be `data` or is it a global variable with a special value?

Answer (score 0):

So there's two issues that you're running into. The first is the case when your `extractperiodtwo()` function doesn't find a value it returns a empty vector. You may write a check into the loop that reports that no data was found for a given entry and handles the error. I recommend a `try`-`catch` block (which I implement in the code below). The second issue has to do with how you're storing the minimum for each iteration.

Here is my solution:

```
function [algo] = getMiniserieone(data, startYear, endYear, time)
  %initialize output
  algo = [zeros(12,1), (1:12)']; %col1 = min(temps), col2 = month
  % loop through months
  yearsToTest = startYear:1:endYear;

  for month = 1:12
    %initialize a year storage, i.e. on the first iteration
    % this will be january minimum temps from startYear:endYear, 
    % on iteration 2, it will be all february temps from startYear:endYear
    % and so on until it completes month == 12.
    lowTempsOverYears = nan(1,length(yearsToTest));

    for yearNum = 1:length(yearsToTest)
      %edit: forgot to paste this line, sorry.
      year = yearsToTest(yearNum);

      p = extractperiodtwo(data, year, month, time);

      q = min(p);

      try
        %try appending the min
        lowTempsOverYears(yearNum) = q;
      catch
        fprintf(2, ...
          '\nNo data found for month=%d, year=%d.\n  Skipping...\n', ...
          month, ...
          year);
      continue
      end
    end
    % inner loop is over, now we need the minimum of mins for the month
    algo(month, 1) = min(lowTempsOverYears,[],'omitnan');
  end

end
```

So what i've done is added a second vector, `lowTempsOverYears` that tracks the `min(p)` for each month over the `startYear:endYear` interval. Then I get the minimum of that and store it in the corresponding row of the month, in the output variable. I initialize `lowTempsOverYears` with `nan()` because it allows me to later take the `min()` with the `'omitnan'` flag set to true, effectively ignoring any nan that appear in the vector.

#### Alternatively

You could capture all the temps over the years and months in a matrix and then perform the statistic of your choice. For example, the inside of your function could be:

```
function algo = getMiniserieone(data, startYear, endYear, time)
    algo = [zeros(12,1), (1:12)'];
    yearsToTest = startYear:1:endYear;
    % create local storage of values as matrix
    v = nan(12,length(yearsToTest));
    %loop
    for month = 1:12
      for yearNum = 1:length(yearsToTest)
        % current year to gather data from
        year = yearsToTest(yearNum);
        % p could be scalar, vector, empty
        p = extractperiodtwo(data, year, month, time);
        % q is scalar or empty
        q = min(p);
        try
          %try inserting the min temp
          v(month,yearNum) = q;
        catch
          fprintf(2,'\nNo data at month=%d, year=%d.\n  Skipping...\n', ...
            month, year ...
            );
        continue
        end
      end
    end
    % now all data is stored in a matrix perform statistic
    algo(:,1) = min(v, [], 2, 'omitnan');
end
```